# Specify Font Size Color Bold Italic Underline in R Studio Console

Tags: r, fonts, console, format

Any way to change the console font on a line by line basis?

I am using R Studio.

Written some code as an example of what I want (obviously doesn't work).

```
print("Hello", bold = T, color = #FF0000, size = 12)

print("Hello also", underline = T, color = #0000FF, size = 8)
```

Comment: I'd be concerned that you are using the console to produce formatting output. Typically one would generate some formatted output file rather than trying to change the console itself.

Comment: With the `crayon` package you can do, for example, `cat(bold(red("Hello")))`. Other colors and formatting options are available, but I don't know of a way to increase the font size of the output.